# how to do fixed nav, footer and content of remaining height without javascript or display:table?

Tags: html, css, dom

Working on something that requires this type of layout:

[image]

i need the content to have an implied size of the remaining space on the screen. i tried many things

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    </div><!-- /content -->


    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

this works with display table technique:

```
#wrapper {display: table; height: 100%; width: 100%; background: yellow;}
#header { display: table-row; background: black;height: 50px;}
#container { display: table-row; height: 100% }
#footer {display: table-row;background: black; height: 50px;}
```

but how would I do it without it?

```
#wrapper {width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; min-height: 800px;}
#header {position: relative; width: 100%; height: 42px;}
#footer {height: 45px; width: 100%; background: #000; position: absolute; bottom: 0; overflow-y: hidden;}
```

also I dont want the content to be position:absolute

Comment: Why do you want to do it without using `display: table`?

Comment: no particular reason, except for IE7, just wanted to see if there's anything else out there, guess not.

Comment: No, there isn't a non-JS solution for IE7.  That's the trouble with supporting antique browsers: you just can't have nice things.  The market share is so low on IE7 and the lack of support for `display: table` isn't going to impair accessibility, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @nuway, I see. Well, in that case, I think `position: absolute` is the only option, might even work in IE6. But actually I'm with cimmanon. A fallback for IE7 and below that does not impact usability too much is absolutely enough.

Comment: another thing i dont like about display:table-cell is the content needs to have some element in it for it to be 100% of the remaining height. Im gonna be using it to ajax stuff into it, and am afraid some flickering might occur

Comment: did you test it? I would not know why `display: table` should do more flickering than other techniques. Well, `display: fixed` should prevent it, because in that case your header and footer would be independent from your content. But as far as I understand, fixing those is not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution i found for this is using css3's new calc method.
I also test for its availabilty with modernizr, and if its not available, I manually set the height of the container area with JS.

Answer (score 1):

This might work, if you can live with fixed heights:

```
body, html, #wrapper, #content
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header,
#footer
{
    position: relative;
    height: 42px;
    background: red;
}
#content
{
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin:-42px 0;
    padding: 42px 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYPDa/5/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">This is my header
</div>

<div id="content">This is my content
</div><!-- /content -->


<div id="footer">This is my footer
</div>
</div>
```

And css goes like this

```
#wrapper {width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
position: relative; 
min-height: 800px;}


#header {position: relative; 
width: 100%; 
height: 42px; 
background-color:#CA3A3A;}


#content{background-color:#089ED0;
min-height: 800px;}


#footer {height: 45px; 
width: 100%; 
background-color:#CA3A3A; 
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0; 
overflow-y: hidden;}
```

Comment: that does not do it, i need the container to be the size of remaining space between header and footer

Comment: you can adjust the height of #content{min-height} for that according to your need.

Comment: i dont have a number that the height is gonna be - it'll be different on different size browser windows

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in the past:
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: thats a link to a footer library, thanks but not what im after